# iCalendar appointment is a 'not supported calendar message.ics'

Tags: python-2.7, email, outlook, icalendar

Trying to automate sending an Outlook calendar invite via python. I am able to send the email and attach the invite; however, the invite is a 'not supported calendar message.ics'. I have spent the last two weeks trying to figure out how to do this. I even tried using win32com.client; but that package does not enable you to send the email from a separate account as I had [posted about here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543958/9274889).

Below is the code I used to generate and send the 'not supported calendar message.ics':

```
# email related imports

import smptlib
import email
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders

# calendar related imports

import icalendar
from icalendar import Calendar, Parameters, Todo
from icalendar.prop import vDatetime, vCalAddress, vText, vInt, vBoolean, vDDDTypes
import uuid

#other imports

import pytz
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta


# set people parameters

sender = 'thing1@example.com'
recipients = 'thing2@example.com'

attendee = vCalAddress(recipients)
attendee.params['cn'] = vText('Thing 1')
attendee.params['RSVP'] = vText('TRUE')

organizer = vCalAddress(sender)
organizer.params['cn'] = vText('Thing 2')

the_sender = vCalAddress(sender)
the_sender.params['cn'] = vText('Thing 2')

# set timing parameters 

location = 'Home'
tz = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific") # timezone to use for our dates -- change 
as needed
appt_time = tz.localize(datetime(2018, 1, 31, 12, 0))
duration = 30
reminder_min = 15

# set info parameters

subject = 'My Cool Event'
description = 'this better work!'
summary = 'python calendar invite testing'


# create calendar object

cal = icalendar.Calendar()
cal.add('prodid', vText('-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN'))
cal.add('version', vInt(2.0))
cal.add('method', vText('REQUEST'))
cal.add('X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN', vBoolean(True)) # creates one instance of the event

# create the timezone 

tz = icalendar.Timezone()
tz.add('tzid', vText('Pacific Standard Time'))
cal.add_component(tz)

# create the calendar event

event = icalendar.Event()
event.add('method', vText('REQUEST'))
event.add('tzid', vText('Pacific Standard Time'))
event.add('attendee', attendee, encode=0)
event.add('class', vText('PUBLIC'))
event.add('created', vDDDTypes(datetime.now()))
event.add('description', vText(description))
event.add('dtend', vDDDTypes((appt_time + timedelta(minutes = duration))))
event.add('dtstart', vDDDTypes(appt_time))
event.add('location', vText(location))
event.add('from', the_sender)
event.add('organizer', the_sender)
event.add('priority', vInt(5))
event.add('sequence', vInt(0))
event.add('summary', vText(summary))
event.add('transp', vText('opaque')) # Specifies whether or not this appointment is intended to be visible in availability searches
event.add('uid',vText(uuid.uuid4()))
event.add('X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS', vText('BUSY')) # sets the busy status of the appointment to busy
event.add('X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE', vInt(1)) # sets the importance of the appointment (0,1,2)
event.add('X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER', vBoolean(False))
event.add('X-MS-OLK-APPTSEQTIME', vDDDTypes(datetime.now()))
event.add('X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION', vBoolean(False)) # specifies whether the location is being automatically populated with recipients of type RESOURCE.
event.add('X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE', vInt(0)) # specifies the type of conferencing that is enabled on the appointment

# set an alarm for a reminder notice

alarm = icalendar.Alarm()
alarm.add("action", "DISPLAY")
alarm.add('description', "Reminder")
alarm.add("TRIGGER;RELATED=START", "-PT{0}M".format(reminder_min))
event.add_component(alarm)
cal.add_component(event)

# write calendar event to file

open('PythonCalendarEvent_1.ics', 'w').writelines(cal.to_ical())

# generate message with (Multi-Purpose Internet Mail Extensions)

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["From"] = sender
msg['To'] = recipients

# attach calendar invite to email message

filename = "PythonCalendarEvent_1.ics"

cal_part = MIMEBase('text', 'calendar', **{'method' : 'REQUEST', 'name' : filename})    
cal_part.set_payload(open(filename,"rb").read())
cal_part.set_type('text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST; component = VEVENT')
email.Encoders.encode_base64(cal_part)
cal_part.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/calendar')
cal_part.add_header('charset', 'UTF-8')
cal_part.add_header('component', 'VEVENT')
cal_part.add_header('method', 'REQUEST')
cal_part.add_header('Content-class', 'urn:content-classes:appointment')
cal_part.add_header('Content-ID', 'calendar_message')
cal_part.add_header('Content Description', filename)
cal_part.add_header("Filename", filename)
cal_part.add_header("Path", filename)
msg.attach(cal_part)

# send the email at last

s =  smtplib.SMTP(_insert_host_as_string_here_)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Another interesting note: if the invite is forwarded, the ics is recognized. For example I generate the email to send to myself and I receive it as a 'not supported calendar message.ics'. If I then forward the invite to my coworker, he sees it as a regular calendar invite. I tested to see if this was just my install; however, he replicated the code and had the same issue--first message was not recognized, but the forwarded invite to me was.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything further.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this FOREVER but I figured out a hack that avoids the problem...

The problem is that the TZ info is getting mangled by icalendar when it does its to_ical() function.

For the sake of our example, let's say that your timezone is 'America/New_York' when you create your dates and then feed them to icalendar, it eventually generates DTSTART/DTEND that look like this:

DTSTART;TZID=EDT;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180622T123000
DTEND;TZID=EDT;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20180622T133000

Note that it has "conveniently" replaced 'America/New_York' with 'EDT'. Outlook does not think this is a real thing.

Here's the code I used to fix it. Instead of using the raw:

```
open('PythonCalendarEvent_1.ics', 'w').writelines(cal.to_ical())
```

Use this instead:

```
import re
tzname = 'America/New_York'
ical_string = cal.to_ical().decode('utf-8')
ical_string = re.sub(r"TZID=[^;]*", 'TZID='+tzname, ical_string)
ical_bytes = ical_string.encode('utf-8')
open('PythonCalendarEvent_1.ics', 'w').writelines(ical_bytes)
```

If this doesn't fix your problem I'll clean up my full function and post it...